# (Solved) Error building Plutus Application Framework

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, plutus-pab

I am trying to build the Plutus Application Framework. I'm running on Archlinux and both Nix and cabal are installed properly as far as I can tell. I have also set the IOHK Binary Caches.

However when I run:

```
nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command build -f default.nix plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab.components.library
```

I get these errors:

...
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/rybllmjs40pk0b3fnvfd4hn1r37pi81a-yaml-lib-yaml-0.11.7.0-ghc-8.10.4.20210212-env.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/q93ricp61fyv11nncqqsc1lqijafcj6l-zlib-bindings-lib-zlib-bindings-0.1.1.5-config.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/ljdx0lff52b88gysr3zx737lk4vinh8a-zlib-bindings-lib-zlib-bindings-0.1.1.5-ghc-8.10.4.20210212-env.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/39qxl421bhkzks2zrra7vy3yl6qqhsib-zlib-lib-zlib-0.6.2.3-config.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/d121pfapibndwaxhfinb725ahdmkfvpy-zlib-lib-zlib-0.6.2.3-config.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/s7h4anc03c53vmn5lv58b1rnj23l39z6-zlib-lib-zlib-0.6.2.3-ghc-8.10.4.20210212-env.drv' failed to build
...

I am new to all this and would like to know what I'm missing. Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I figured out you have to run the command as root. My issue now is I am flagged I don't have enough space in my root partition. Luckily I already have a new drive so I will come back to the question if I still get an error once I've migrated to the new drive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I transferred my system to a bigger drive. I can confirm running the command as root went without a problem. So I now have a local plutus framework installation. Marked as solved.